# ¿Como relacionar los objetos de 2 arrays en TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, array, angular, typescript, objeto

Hola y gracias de antemano por la ayuda, Estoy trabajando en un proyecto angular y tengo el siguiente problema:

**Recursos**

Desde un servidor con una base de datos recibo dos respuestas, una con una serie de productos y otra con una serie de ordenes o pedidos. Estos datos los almaceno en dos variables como estas.

```
  public ordenes = [];
  public productos = [];
```

Si hago un `console.log()` de ellas me devuelven lo siguiente:

[image: Objeto de ordenes]
[image: Objeto de productos]

Como podrán observar en cada elemento del objeto de ordenes hay un campo con la id de un producto del otro objeto.

**Solución esperada**

Necesito acceder al nombre del producto en cada elemento del objeto ordenes pero no consigo dar con la forma de hacerlo.
Por si sirve de ayuda a la solución el objetivo final es que en el siguiente código justo donde pone "PROBLEMA" poner el nombre del producto "{{o.nombre}}"

```
<div class="container" *ngFor="let o of ordenes">
    <div class="orden">
        <h5 class="producto"><span>Producto:</span> PROBLEMA</h5>
        <h5 class="cantidad"><span>Cantidad:</span> {{o.cantidad}}</h5>
        <h5 class="hora"><span>Hora:</span> {{o.horapedido}}</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="botonera">
        <h5 class="estado"><span>Estado:</span> {{o.estadopedido}}</h5>
        <mat-icon>arrow_drop_down_circle</mat-icon>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tu problema es que en si tus ordenes deberian contener a su vez dentro de cada una los productos asociados a la orden, en pocas palabras cada orden puede contener diferente cantidad de productos, pero en tu caso solo tienes una orden sin productos, piensa por ejemplo en el recibo que te dan en un supermercado al comprar, el recibo viene con la cantidad, el nombre del producto, el iva, etc, pero todos los que sean productos van en el recibo, justo esto es lo que tienes que considerar, la relacion de tus productos deberia ser unificada y no separada como la tienes.

Comment: Conclusion: deberias fusionar los objetos y devolverlos en un array de ordenes, la cual contendra toda la informacion relevante que necesitas.

Comment: Por favor cambia las imágenes por texto. Los ejemplos serian mas funcionales y fáciles de entender.

Comment: Yo me pregunto, ¿qué has intentado? Te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve]. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) y [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/find) para crear la estructura en tu front.

```js
let ordenes = [{
  idProducto: 'tuIdSuperLargo'
}]


let productos = [

  {
    id: 'tuIdSuperLargo',
    nombre: 'Mi producto'
  }
]


let ordenesConProductos = ordenes.map(orden => {

  return {
    //Este campo es nuevo
    nombreProducto: productos.find(x => x.id === orden.idProducto).nombre,
    idProducto: orden.idProducto

  }

})

console.log(ordenesConProductos)
```

Answer (score 0):

Interpreto tu código...
1.- tienes dos variables ordenes y productos que son dos arrays.
2.- console.log(), no muestra el nombre del producto (y este es tu problema).

Lo que yo haría:

1.- crea una clase que represente a cada producto, ahí te aseguras de que tenga un nombre y luego se lo asignas.
2.- crea una clase que represente cada órden o pedido, en ella, una de las propiedades tiene que ser un objeto que corresponda a la clase producto, y se lo asignas.
3.- Para acceder al nombre del producto es sencillo, recuerda que tienes el producto dentro del pedido y con ello todos los campos/propiedades del mismo.

Solución 2.

1.- Crea una nueva clase con los datos que te falten y haz un mapeo

Comment: Un poco de código para apoyar tu propuesta sería muy bien recibido. Te invito a repasar [answer]. Saludos